# How to enable maven to deploy the ear to the app. server automatically

Tags: java, deployment, maven-2, jboss, ear

I am using maven2 with a struts-hibernate Java EE project and developing with myEclipse. 
When I run a maven build, clean&install, it generates myProject.ear under the myProject_ear\target folder as usual. However, I have to copy this ear file from that folder to the ..jboss-4.2.2.GA_2\server\default\deploy folder in order to deploy, and again turn back to eclipse and start the server.

It is because of my project has not a standard Java EE skeleton I think. However, if there is a way to tell maven to deploy my ear under the ..\deploy folder of jboss automatically, I would be glad to hear that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is during development, my suggestion would be to use the WTP support and to **Run** [your project] **on Server**. And if for whatever reason you cannot use the WTP, then my second suggestion would be to use the [JBoss Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/) and the following goals:

> - [`jboss:hard-deploy`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/hard-deploy-mojo.html)
>     Deploy a file or directory to JBoss by copying
>     files directly to the server
>     deployment directory.
> - [`jboss:hard-undeploy`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/hard-undeploy-mojo.html)
>     Undeploy a file or directory to JBoss
>     by removing files from the server
>     deployment directory.

From the examples:

> ### [Deploying the files by direct copy](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/examples/deploy-undeploy-examples.html)
>
> The plugin goals hard-deploy and
>   hard-undeploy can be used to deploy
>   files or directories by copying
>   directly to the deploy directory of
>   the server. The first step is to
>   configure the location of the server
>   and the file to be deployed.
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <build>
>     ...
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>1.4.1</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <jbossHome>/usr/jboss-4.2.3.GA</jbossHome>
>           <serverName>all</serverName>
>           <fileName>target/my-project.war</fileName>
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>       ...
>     </plugins>
>     ...
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```
>
> The file can now be deployed and
>   undeployed using the appropriate
>   goals.
>
> ```
> mvn jboss:hard-deploy
> mvn jboss:hard-undeploy
> ```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your early reply. I will try and let you know asap.